# QML DropArea External Files Fails

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make it so I can drag and drop external files (from Explorer) into a region of my application and it will list some information about those files. The problem is that every time I drop them into a DropArea, the application says it's not allowed for some reason.

I've researched this and many years ago this wasn't supported, and some users later then claimed there was a bug... but everything I've read so far says that it was fixed and that it should be working.

The problem is driving me crazy, because from what I've been reading it SHOULD work... What am I missing?

Here is a video of what happens.
https://puu.sh/HLz3S/39e98ed95d.mp4

I'm running the following specs:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Qt 5.15.2 (Shown in video)
- Qt Creator 4.15 (Shown in video)

This is the code... everything else is default from a new Qt Quick application...

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    title: 'Accordion'
    visible: true

    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDropped: {
            console.log("Dropped");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I just found out that if I run the application directly through the compiled EXE, instead of through Qt Creators "Run (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)" functionality it works as expected! That is to say, I'm able to drop files on the DropArea.... I'm just not sure why it doesn't work if it's ran using Qt Creator... Debugging will be very annoying like this, does anyone have any thoughts as to how I can make it work via Qt Creator too?

Comment: The version of Qt that I use when compiling QtCreator (5.15.2) is different from the version that your program runs. According to the message shown at the bottom of QtCreator it indicates that you are using Qt 5.15.0 so it may be a bug of that version. I recommend you check which version you are using. For example now there is no QtCreator compiled with Qt6 but I can use Qt6 (I also use Qt4) in the latest version of QtCreator

Comment: @eyllanesc I actually updated from version 5.12 because 5.12 was also having the same issue... I assumed updating might fix the problem, it didn't. However, for my own sanity I decided to try and run the compiled application directly by launching the EXE instead of using Qt Creators run functionality... To my surprise, running direct through the compiled EXE allowed file dropping.... I'm just not sure why it doesn't if it's ran using Qt Creator... Do you have any ideas? It will be a pain to debug like this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else experiences this... I found out this ONLY happens if Qt Creator is Run as Admin... Not sure why this is the case, I'd expect it the other way around.